# Direction of our devotional prayers

Tags: practice, prayer

Are indicated specific directions for our devotional prayers?
For example N,S,W,E? 
what about Vishnu or Shiva or Devi practice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to seek the relevance of these four directions then follow the discussions done between **"Garuda"** and **"Galava"** in **"Bhagwat Yana Parva"** of Mahabharat.

Garuda explains the relevance of all the 4 directions in very minute details, why they are named such and what should be the directions for all kinds of prayers (regular prayers, pitr-tarpan and others.)

Refer to section [SECTION CVIII](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05108.htm), [SECTION CIX](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05109.htm), [SECTION CX](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05110.htm), [SECTION CXI](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05111.htm).

The details are quite large, I hope they help you, please go through these sections.

***Just to summarize:***

Regular prayers (the usual ones) should be done facing east as it is the sacred direction as explained below:

> That quarter towards which Surya the illuminator of the universe first
>   riseth; where, at eve, the Sadhyas engage in their ascetic
>   austerities; where that Intelligence, which pervades the whole
>   universe first springeth; where the two eyes of Dharma, as well as he
>   himself, are stationed; where the clarified butter first poured in
>   sacrifice subsequently flowed all around; that quarter, O best of all
>   regenerate persons, is the gate of Day and Time.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for taking time to answer to my question.

Comment: @KamakuraKing if an answer satisfies you, that answer is apt to what is asked in question by you, you can click tick mark and accept the answer!